# Validate last 2 letters into dynamic query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dynamic

Im doing a Dynamic Query into ASP.NET using SQL Server 2016.

Basically i have some checkbox and textbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_Precio" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_Precio_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrecio" runat="server" CssClass="enjoy-css" style="margin-bottom: 0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_Modelo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_Modelo_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtModelo" runat="server" CssClass="enjoy-css" style="margin-bottom: 0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnBuscar_Click" />
```

These are validated in `chk_Modelo_CheckedChanged`.

Inside `btnBuscar_Click` i have:

```cs
protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT p.OrderId AS Orden, p.OrderDate as Fechadecompra, '$'+Convert(varchar,convert(money,p.Amount),1) as PrecioCompra, c.ModelCar as Modelo, b.Description_Brand as Marca, c.Color, t.Description_Transmision as Transmision, s.StatusName AS Estado FROM PurchaseOrder AS p INNER JOIN Cars AS c ON p.IdCar = c.IdCar INNER JOIN Brand AS b ON c.IdBrand = b.IdBrand INNER JOIN TransmisionType AS t ON c.IdTransmision = t.IdTransmision INNER JOIN Status AS s on c.IdStatus = s.IdStatus where ";
            string varprecio = txtPrecio.Text;
            string varModelo = txtModelo.Text;
            try
            {

                if (varprecio != "")
                {
                    query += "(p.Amount = '"+varprecio +"') or";
                }
                else if(varModelo != "")
                {
                    query += "(c.ModelCar = '"+varModelo +"') or";
                }
                string str = "Data Source=DESKTOP-77G5EDB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TallerDB;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(str);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                sqlConnection.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dtgv_Compras.DataSource = dr;
                dtgv_Compras.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('ERROR: " + ex.Message + "')</script>");
            }
        }
```

**My question is:**
How can i validate if my query ends with: `OR`, delete these `OR` and my query finish correctly.

```
query += "(p.Amount = '"+varprecio +"') or";
```

F.E.:

```
SELECT p.OrderId AS Orden, p.OrderDate as Fechadecompra, '$'+Convert(varchar,convert(money,p.Amount),1) as PrecioCompra, c.ModelCar as Modelo, b.Description_Brand as Marca, c.Color, t.Description_Transmision as Transmision, s.StatusName AS Estado 
FROM PurchaseOrder AS p 
INNER JOIN Cars AS c ON p.IdCar = c.IdCar 
INNER JOIN Brand AS b ON c.IdBrand = b.IdBrand 
INNER JOIN TransmisionType AS t ON c.IdTransmision = t.IdTransmision 
INNER JOIN Status AS s on c.IdStatus = s.IdStatus where (p.Amount = '5000')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use IndexOf("or") to check for "or" and that will give you the position of where "or" starts and then use Substring() to parse the query with the "or" removed.

Comment: Are you only using two input fields?

Comment: @user7908029, no im using 2 input fields, ill modify the code.

Comment: Obligatory sql injection warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your button click.

```
protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "SELECT p.OrderId AS Orden, p.OrderDate as Fechadecompra, '$'+Convert(varchar,convert(money,p.Amount),1) as PrecioCompra, c.ModelCar as Modelo, b.Description_Brand as Marca, c.Color, t.Description_Transmision as Transmision, s.StatusName AS Estado FROM PurchaseOrder AS p INNER JOIN Cars AS c ON p.IdCar = c.IdCar INNER JOIN Brand AS b ON c.IdBrand = b.IdBrand INNER JOIN TransmisionType AS t ON c.IdTransmision = t.IdTransmision INNER JOIN Status AS s on c.IdStatus = s.IdStatus ";
    string varprecio = txtPrecio.Text;
    string varModelo = txtModelo.Text;
    try
    {
        if (varprecio != "" || varModelo != "")
            query += "where ";
        if (varprecio != "")
        {
            query += "(p.Amount = '" + varprecio + "')";
            if (varModelo != "")
                query += " or ";
        }

        if (varModelo != "")
        {
            query += "(c.ModelCar = '" + varModelo + "')";
        }
        string str = "Data Source=DESKTOP-77G5EDB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TallerDB;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtgv_Compras.DataSource = dr;
        dtgv_Compras.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('ERROR: " + ex.Message + "')</script>");
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you. Please let me know if you will still facing issue.

Comment: Thanks, it really works for me, i only change my main query deleting the last 'where'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this so you don't have to check whether they are blank or not

```
query += "('" + varprecio +"' = '''' or p.Amount = '" + varprecio +"') AND"
query += "('" + varModelo +"' = '''' or c.ModelCar = '"+varModelo +"')";
```

Which will give you

```
WHERE ('' = '' OR p.amount = '') AND ('' = '' or c.ModelCar = '')
```

or

```
WHERE ('abc' = '' OR p.amount = 'abc') AND ('xyz' = '' or c.ModelCar = 'xyz')
```

so if they are blank they are ignored on the SQL side.

Comment: if `varprecio  = ''` then  the first `'' = ''`  is correct, your query returns all data. It will skip `filter by varModelo`

Comment: Thanks! i'll test it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying in my work with oracle and i found this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('select * from table where condicion = value or', 1, (LENGTH('select * from table where condicion = value or') - 2)) 
FROM dual where (SUBSTR ('select * from table where condicion = value or', -2,LENGTH('select * from table where condicion = value or')) = 'or');
```

Query:

```
select * from table where condicion = value or
```

Result:

[image]

I'll convert later to transact-sql in case someone uses the code into oracle.